# AHK: Can someone make my script hold right & left mouse to drag the mouse?

Tags: autohotkey

Hello guys i have this strip in AHK....when i press right & left mouse the mouse will start moving....but i want to hold right & left to drag the mouse so when i don't hold it stops, its like "if condition", if not holding the mouse stops.

The script:

```
~RButton & LButton:: ;This is just a note
While GetKeyState("RButton", "P") AND GetKeyState("LButton", "P")
{   
     DllCall("mouse_event", uint, 1, int, -3, int, 3, uint, 1, int, 0)
     Sleep, 10
     DllCall("mouse_event", uint, 1, int, -3, int, 3, uint, 0, int, 0)
     Sleep, 10
     DllCall("mouse_event", uint, 1, int, -3, int, 3, uint, 1, int, 0)
     Sleep, 2
     DllCall("mouse_event", uint, 1, int, -3, int, 3, uint, 0, int, 0)
     Sleep, 10
     DllCall("mouse_event", uint, 1, int, -3, int, 3, uint, 1, int, 0)
     Sleep, 10
     DllCall("mouse_event", uint, 1, int, -3, int, 3, uint, 0, int, 0)
     Sleep, 10
} Return


F12::ExitApp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
   F10::

   Send {F1 down}{F12 down}

   KeyWait F10

   Return

  F10 up::Send {F12 up}{F1 up}
```

you can change the keys with your keys